# How can I disable DEP for a single application (32 bit app, Win 7x64)

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-7-x64, dep

Adobe Acrobat Pro 9.5, despite a couple of hundred of service pack fixes, still cannot scan without crashing.  It's a well-known issue, and the solution is to disable DEP because Acrobat is buggy (or has intentional self-modifying code, but I hope not).

As much as it'd be nice to scan, I'm not willing to disable this security feature for my whole PC.  So I changed my DEP settings to Always On, but Opt Out.

When I attempt to set DEP Off for the Acrobat.exe application, however, I get this message:

```
  This program must run with data execution protection (DEP) enabled.
  You cannot turn off DEP for this program.
```

Well, that's dandy, but the opposite of what I need.  Before I resort to running it in a VM or some horrible workaround to make my $1000 app not crash, is there any way to do this for a single app that Windows 7x64 will actually allow?

I have a feeling that what it's failing to tell me is that you can't disable DEP for **any** 32 bit app on the 64 bit OS, but it doesn't say that and I can't confirm that elsewhere.

Comment: The Compatibility Administrator (part of the Compatibility Toolkit, available from the MS download site) might have an option to do this.